# BeautifulSoup tag.children only gets odd-numbered elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to move the elements from one tag to another tag using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me too</p><p>me three</p><p>me 4</p><p>5</p>")
d = soup.new_tag('div')
for tag in soup.body.children:
    d.append(tag)
```

However, this yields...

```
>>> d
<div><p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me three</p><p>5</p></div>
```

Only the odd-numbered elements were moved. I checked `soup.body.children` to see what it looks like (before moving anything), and all of the tags appear to be there:

```
>>> list(soup.body.children)
[<p>I wish I was bold.</p>, <p>me too</p>, <p>me three</p>, <p>me 4</p>, <p>5</p>]
```

When I iterate over `list(soup.body.children)`, then everything works as expected:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me too</p><p>me three</p><p>me 4</p><p>5</p>")
d = soup.new_tag('div')
for tag in list(soup.body.children):
    d.append(tag)
>>> d
<div><p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me too</p><p>me three</p><p>me 4</p><p>5</p></div>
```

Why does iterating over `soup.body.children` only access odd-numbered tags, but iterating over `list(soup.body.children)` accesses all of them?

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: @StephenCowley `lxml`, but why would the parser make a difference? I thought that once you've parsed the markup, it's all just native soup objects.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if it mattered, but just wanted to match your configuration as close as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append to the `d` tag in the first case, you are actually changing the size of `soup.body.children` as you go, since it *moves the tags* from `soup` to `d`.

Thus it grabs the tag at 0 and moves it to `d`. When it goes back for tag at 1, they have all shifted over, and it grabs the tag originally at index 2.

One way to see this in action is to actually print `list(soup.body.children)` in each iteration. Something like this:

```
for i, tag in enumerate(soup.body.children):
    d.append(tag)
    print(i)
    print(list(soup.body.children))
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 #<-- It's accessing this element
[<p>me too</p>, <p>me three</p>, <p>me 4</p>, <p>5</p>]

1
[<p>me too</p>, <p>me 4</p>, <p>5</p>]

2
[<p>me too</p>, <p>me 4</p>]
```

Comment: Of course! That's why making a copy with `list` doesn't fail. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the items being moved from 'soup' to 'd' are affected the iterator, i.e. removing them and changing the 'soup' generator as you iterate through the items.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me too</p><p>me three</p><p>me 4</p><p>5</p>")
d = soup.new_tag('div')
children = list(soup.body.children).copy()
for tag in children:
    d.append(tag)


print(d)
```

Creating a copy of the list solves the problem.

### output

```
<div><p>I wish I was bold.</p><p>me too</p><p>me three</p><p>me 4</p><p>5</p></div>
```

Comment: `.copy()` is unnecessary, since `list()` already makes a copy, as I showed in the OP.